# Tmux - how to execute a command automatically when changing window panes?

Tags: linux, tmux

Is there a way to execute a command automatically every time I change panes in tmux?

Of course I could execute it manually, but I'm trying to fix a glitch in colors automatically [1]. I'm using tmux 2.6, on Ubuntu 18.04.

thanks!

--

*[1] for context: I'm changing pane colors automatically based on the current user (so root would have a different pane color), and change the fg/bg based on active/inactive window. Everything works fine, but there's some edge cases where I need to issue a `tmux refresh-client`. So I'm trying to have the refresh-client running automatically every time I change panes.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think these should do the trick:

```
tmux set-hook window-pane-changed refresh-client
tmux set-hook session-window-changed refresh-client
tmux set-hook session-changed refresh-client
```

But I only tested it with `'display-message hi'` as the command, so it’s possible that the `refresh-client` won’t work as expected.

Comment: Spot on, thanks @Lucas!  Worked like a charm. In my case I only needed the first one (`window-pane-changed`), but also useful to know there are other triggers as well.

Comment: Suppose that I have a tmux session, with vim already open. Can I force this refresh-client command each time I load a new vim file?

When I use vim to open text files inside tmux (on my local machine, not connected to a remote server), the text is always garbled, showing some rows from the previous screen (the previous screen can be vim or another program).

Answer (score 1):

I created a script to notify me a windows is zoomed:

~/.byobu/hook.conf

```
set-hook session-window-changed {
    run-shell "bash ~/.byobu/bin/set_status_bg_color.sh"
}

set-hook window-pane-changed {
    run-shell "bash ~/.byobu/bin/set_status_bg_color.sh"
}
```

~/.byobu/keybindings.tmux

```
bind z {
   resize-pane -Z

   source ~/.byobu/hook.conf                                # if you just put the content of hook.conf in .tmux.conf, it won't work properly
   run-shell "bash ~/.byobu/bin/set_status_bg_color.sh"     # the order of the two statements is important
}
```

~/.byobu/bin/set_status_bg_color.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

tmux list-panes -F "#F" | grep "Z" > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  tmux set -g status-bg magenta #blue
  tmux set -g status-left " #(echo #{pane_current_path} | sed 's#$HOME#~#g') | ZOOMED-IN "
else
  tmux set -g status-bg grey19 #default #green # Try default first. If the color of the status after unzooming doesn't look right, change the color
  tmux set -g status-left " #(echo #{pane_current_path} | sed 's#$HOME#~#g') "
fi
```

PS: The script finally works.